# How do I properly partially differentiate with constant $p$ in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, entropy, differentiation

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> a one component system is described by the following equations
>
> $$U=\frac{A^2}{4}NT^2\exp \left(\frac{V^2}{N^2}\right),\qquad p=T^2f(v)$$
>
> where $v = \frac{V}{N},\,\,A\in ℝ$.

Through clever use of symmetry of second derivatives of $S$ I got to the following equation for $p$ and $S$:

$$
p = -T^2\frac{A^2}{2}v\text{ Exp}[v^2];\qquad\qquad S =\frac{A^2}{2}NT\text{ Exp}\left[v^2\right] 
$$
I believe these are correct. Now I thought of using the definition formula
$$
C_p=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{p\,=\text{ const.}}
$$
and I thought to myself "hey! The functions present in $p$ are also in $S$! If I factor them out correctly, I'll get the desired dependence easily":
$$
S = -\frac{pN^2}{VT}
$$
That would be easy enough! But then I realized i could just as much "factor out" $\sqrt{p}$, kill all dependence on $T$ and arrrive at $C_p = 0$.

Why can this happen, what did I do wrong and how do I handle this correctly?

**EDIT:** Ok, we came to the conclusion that $V = V(T,p)$ which I didn't consider when derivating (thank you, Andrew), but now I have completely no idea how to solve this. From the equation of $p$ one can't get $V=V(T,p)$ and without it I can't get $\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p$ and solve this. **How do I correctly find $C_p$?**

Comment: How would you "factor out" $\sqrt{p}$?

Comment: What are you trying to determine?

Comment: You just treat $p$ as any other constant, like $N$ and $V$ when deriving $S$ w.r.t $T$. That's all the definition for $C_{\rm p}$ says.

Comment: @ChetMiller I' trying to find $C_p$ correctly

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape yes, but in the $S$ I found there is no $p$ to be held constant. I can artificially put it there, which changes the dependance of $S$ on $T$, but since im then doing $\partial_T$, that would change the outcome of the derivative and therefore $C_p$

Comment: @DavideMorgante I see now that it wouldn't work so easily with the $\sqrt$ since $p<0$, but let's say I factor out $p^2$: $S = \frac{A^2}{2}NT\text{ Exp}\left[ v^2\right] = p^2\frac{2}{A^2 T^3}\frac{N^3}{V^2}\text{ Exp}\left[ -v^2\right]$. As you can see, the dependace on $T$ is wildly different

Comment: @OndraJanoška Yes, but as Andrew pointed out, you still have dependence on $T$ in the volume. Since you have only a functional relation for $p$ and $S$, you should try to find a formula for $\left.\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right|_p$ which depends only on their derivatives. Have a look a [Maxwell's square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_square)

Answer (score 3):

Yes we can write $S$ as a function of $V$ and $p$ but it does not follow that $(\partial S/\partial T)_p = 0$. Rather:
$$
S=S(V,p)
$$
$$
dS = \left. \frac{\partial S}{\partial p}\right|_V dp + 
 \left. \frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right|_p dV
$$
so
$$
\left. \frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right|_p = 
 \left. \frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right|_p \left. \frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right|_p
$$
The fact that we can write $S$ as a function of $p$ and $V$ does not "kill all the dependence on $T$" as you put it. The dependence on $T$ is still there because $V$ depends on $T$ (at any given pressure).

Comment: So I did half the job factoring out $p$ and now I would have to find $V = V(T,p)$ and differentiate it? That seems like an awfully lot of work. Is there a way I was *supposed* to do it that would be simpler?

Comment: I take it that $N$ here is constant. If so then you have a formula for $S(T,V)$ so you can find $(\partial{S}/\partial{T})_V$ and thus $C_V$. Now you want $C_p$. There is a universal equation relating $C_p - C_V$ to functions which can be found from the equation of state, and you have the equation of state (the expression for $p$ in terms of $V$ and $T$).

Comment: yes, $C_p-C_V = T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p^2 \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_T^{-1}$, but that requires me to know $V=V(T,p)$, which is impossible to write from my $p=p(V,T)$

Comment: @OndraJanoška now use reciprocity relation to get $(\partial V/\partial T)_p$ in terms of partial derivativatives of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

I have some hints for you on how to solve for Cp.

$C_p$ is defined as $$C_p=\frac{1}{N}\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P$$Enthalpy H is defined as $$H=U+PV$$You have equations for U and P, so you know H = H(T,V).  Using this, the differential of H is $$dH=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial V}\right)_TdV$$So, $$\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_V+\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial V}\right)_T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P$$The differential of P in terms of dV and dT is:  $$dP=\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_TdV$$Since, at constant pressure, dP=0, this allows you to express $\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P$ in terms of $\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V$ and $\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. This borders with something else that I deeply don't understand. At constant pressure dP = 0 i.e. there is no small change of pressure. But how can then $\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\neq 0$? We just said P doesn't change, how can then I calculate how P changes (which it doesn't) with T?

Comment: This is a mathematical question.  You need to brush up on partial differentiation fundamentals.

Comment: could you please point me towards the relevant topic? Most of fundamentals I took were "it's like a regular derivative, you just keep other variables constant"

Comment: Do you really think that the partial of pressure with respect to temperature at constant volume is zero?